# What kind of dragon slayer magic Acnologia Wields

Tags: fairy-tail

What kind of dragon slayer magic did Acnologia use to slay 10,000 dragon 400 years in the past?

Comment: Is your question as to what element Acnalogia employs in his casting of dragon slayer magic?

Comment: yes that is my basic question

Comment: I think, [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/37733/37235) should answer your question.